# Loading multiple saved tensorflow/keras models for prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use multiple saved TensorFlow/Keras models for prediction.
My understanding is that I can create multiple models by simply loading different saved models.

```
saved_models_with_weights=[]
for model_path in paths:
    saved_models_with_weights.append(keras.models.load_model(model_path))
```

And for prediction, I can simply iterate through these and get the prediction.

However, I [read](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8538) that Keras has a shared global namespace, and these will result in the wrong prediction.

When I tried the suggested solutions, I get compilation issues like

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

The above error is because in TF 2.0+ it is not available.

My question is related to the way I am loading multiple models.

**Is this still an issue with TF 2.0+?**

Comment: For tf 2.x use `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()`. And also make sure you are using tensorflow.keras library to save and load model. Example `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`. Thanks!